# How to properly draw line in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, drawing

I try to make a game with Libgdx in Java, and I have to draw Trees.
When I try to make and draw the Trees is OK, but it takes a lot of time.
So I try to generate all of the branches in an array and draw it after, but I've a rendering problem.

When I try to make and draw the Trees :
[image: When I try to make and draw the Trees]

When I try to generate first and then draw the Trees, I just see nothing at screen.
But I've the feeling of rendering the same things..

There is the code that running well :

```
public void drawBranch(OrthographicCamera b2dCam, int pointX, int pointY, double directionX, double directionY, float size,
        int lineWidth, int recursion_number) {
    // Finding the End Point of the Vector(line) to draw it
    int x2 = (int) (pointX + directionX * size), y2 = (int) (pointY + directionY * size);
    // Drawing the line from initial to final point

    int lineWidth2 = getCurrentLenght(recursion_number, lineWidth);
    Vector2 start = new Vector2(pointX, pointY);
    Vector2 end = new Vector2(x2, y2);

    // Draw the line
    HelperGraphicsClass.DrawDebugLineToPPM(start, end, lineWidth2, getCurrentColor(recursion_number), b2dCam.combined);

    // If the maximum recursions are reached we need to stop
    if (recursion_number >= CURRENT_RECURSIONS) {           
        return;
    }

    // Finding the size of next branch by shrinking the current branch
    float new_branch_size = size / SHRINK_FACTOR;
    double directionX2;
    double directionY2;
    // Incrementing the recursion_number by 1
    int n2 = recursion_number + 1;

    // Finding the Direction Vector of the next branch
    directionX2 = Math.sin(ANGLE) * directionY + Math.cos(ANGLE) * directionX;
    directionY2 = -(Math.sin(ANGLE) * directionX) + Math.cos(ANGLE) * directionY;
    // Drawing the branch
    drawBranch(b2dCam, x2, y2, directionX2, directionY2, new_branch_size, lineWidth2, n2);

    // // Finding the Direction Vector of the corresponding branch on
    // the other
    // // side i.e. with angle = -ANGLE
    directionX2 = Math.cos(-ANGLE) * directionX + Math.sin(-ANGLE) * directionY;
    directionY2 = -Math.sin(-ANGLE) * directionX + Math.cos(-ANGLE) * directionY;
    // Drawing the twin branch
    drawBranch(b2dCam, x2, y2, directionX2, directionY2, new_branch_size, lineWidth2, n2);

}
```

There is the code that running wrong :

```
public void saveBranch(OrthographicCamera b2dCam, int pointX, int pointY, double directionX, double directionY, float size,
        int lineWidth, int recursion_number) {
    // Finding the End Point of the Vector(line) to draw it
    int x2 = (int) (pointX + directionX * size), y2 = (int) (pointY + directionY * size);
    // Drawing the line from initial to final point
    // g.drawLine(pointX, pointY, x2, y2);
    int lineWidth2 = getCurrentLenght(recursion_number, lineWidth);
    Vector2 start = new Vector2(pointX, pointY);
    Vector2 end = new Vector2(x2, y2);

    memoryTreeBranchs.get(0).add(new TreeBranch(start, end, lineWidth2, getCurrentColor(recursion_number)));

    // If the maximum recursions are reached we need to stop
    if (recursion_number >= CURRENT_RECURSIONS) {
        return;
    }

    // Finding the size of next branch by shrinking the current branch
    float new_branch_size = size / SHRINK_FACTOR;
    double directionX2;
    double directionY2;
    // Incrementing the recursion_number by 1
    int n2 = recursion_number + 1;

    // Finding the Direction Vector of the next branch
    directionX2 = Math.sin(ANGLE) * directionY + Math.cos(ANGLE) * directionX;
    directionY2 = -(Math.sin(ANGLE) * directionX) + Math.cos(ANGLE) * directionY;
    // Drawing the branch
    saveBranch(b2dCam, x2, y2, directionX2, directionY2, new_branch_size, lineWidth2, n2);

    // // Finding the Direction Vector of the corresponding branch on
    // the other
    // // side i.e. with angle = -ANGLE
    directionX2 = Math.cos(-ANGLE) * directionX + Math.sin(-ANGLE) * directionY;
    directionY2 = -Math.sin(-ANGLE) * directionX + Math.cos(-ANGLE) * directionY;
    // Drawing the twin branch
    saveBranch(b2dCam, x2, y2, directionX2, directionY2, new_branch_size, lineWidth2, n2);

}
```

And I draw it like that :

```
public void drawGeneratedBranchs(OrthographicCamera b2dCam) {
    for (int i = 0; i < memoryTreeBranchs.size(); i++) {
        for (TreeBranch tb : memoryTreeBranchs.get(i)) {
            HelperGraphicsClass.DrawDebugLineToPPM(tb.getStart(), tb.getEnd(), tb.getLineWidth(), getCurrentColor(i + 1),
                    b2dCam.combined);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm felling bad, I can't see the differences, since 2 weeks I just can't solve that problem...

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Hey i cant test it right now cause im still at work but im definetly going to at home. this seems odd so
Why are you always placing your new TreeBranch at position 0?
`memoryTreeBranchs.get(0).add(new TreeBranch(start, end, lineWidth2, getCurrentColor(recursion_number)));`

Comment: Thx !!
I always add at position 0, because it's a test ^^.
At end, each position will represent a generation of branches.

Comment: Nobody can help ? ..

Comment: Pls !!

Why don't you response me Till hemmerich ?